# JS Check Date is Within 6 Months of Today

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am using Bootstrap Datepicker, and based on the date selection I need to display a message to the user.

I have never used the [Date Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) before so it's very new to me.

What I need to do is the following;

- allow user to select a date
- display a message / alert based of the logic below

If their selected date is within the last 6 months of today, they quality for discount. 
If their selected date doesn't fall within the last 6 months of today, they don't.

Although it's not working correctly have created a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gaj1gpoL/4/).

Any help would be appreciated. Code also below;

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" placeholder="Year Graduated" value="" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
<p id="rate"></p>
```

JS

```
  function compareDate() {
    // get date from datepicker
    var dateEntered = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
    dateEntered = new Date(dateEntered).getTime();
    //alert("date entered: " + dateEntered);
    // set todays date
    var now = new Date();
    // set date six months before today
    var sixMonthBeforeNow = new Date(now).setTime(now.getTime() - 3 * 28 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    //alert("six months before: " + sixMonthBeforeNow);
    // if date entered is within six months from today
    if (dateEntered > sixMonthBeforeNow) {
      alert("You qualify for the discount rate.");
      $("#rate").html('discount rate');
    }
    // if date entered is over six months from today
    if (dateEntered < sixMonthBeforeNow) {
      alert("you graduated more than six months ago");
      $("#rate").html('no discount');
    }
  }

  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    weekStart: 1,
    daysOfWeekHighlighted: "6,0",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
  });

  $("#datepicker").change(function() {
    compareDate();
  });
```

Note: I'd prefer not to use any other 3rd party JS library / plugin.

Comment: You should take a look at `moment.js`, or some other library that allows for the use of an internet clock to get the current time.  `Date` defaults to the system time on the client, which is typically in their control to alter at their whim.

Comment: @Taplar—all values should be validated at the server anyway, so why introduce another point of failure and delay? The local clock can be checked against the web server.

Comment: @RobG Of course the values must be validated on the server.  We are talking about front end validation that serves the primary purpose of increasing the UX of the site for the user.  Allowing a user to open your UI and choose a date that is not valid, only due to their system clock being wrong, is terrible UI.  Whether you use an internet clock or reference the server clock (which to the client is an internet clock) to determine the date ranges that the user should be shown, is a small part of that problem.  The primary problem being, the user shouldn't be given options that are invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful with date arithmetic because it's not symmetric due to the uneven length of months, so you need rules to deal with it. E.g. what date is exactly 6 months before 31 August?

Before answering, consider:

1. 28 February plus 6 months is 28 August
2. 1 March plus 6 months is 1 September.
3. So what date is 6 months *before* 29, 30 and 31 August? Is it 28 February or 1 March?

Similar issues arise for any last day of a month where the month 6 months previous doesn't have 31 days. Should the limit be the 30th of the month or the 1st of the following month? When you've answered that question, then you can devise an algorithm to deliver the right answer and then the code to implement it.

If you want such cases to set the date to the end of the month 6 months before, then you can check the month resulting from subtracting 6 months and if it's not 6, set it to the last day of the previous month, e.g.

```js
function sixMonthsPrior(date) {
  // Copy date so don't affect original
  var d = new Date(date);
  // Get the current month number
  var m = d.getMonth();
  // Subtract 6 months
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 6);
  // If the new month number isn't m - 6, set to last day of previous month
  // Allow for cases where m < 6
  var diff = (m + 12 - d.getMonth()) % 12;
  if (diff < 6) d.setDate(0)
  
  return d;
}

// Helper to format the date
function formatDate(d) {
  return d.toLocaleString(undefined, {day:'2-digit', month:'short', year:'numeric'});
}

// Tests
[ new Date(2018, 7,31), // 31 Aug 2018
  new Date(2018, 8, 1), //  1 Sep 2018
  new Date(2018,11,31), // 31 Dec 2018
  new Date(2019, 2,31)  // 31 Mar 2019
].forEach( d => console.log(formatDate(d) + ' => ' + formatDate(sixMonthsPrior(d))));
```

If that is't the logic you wish to apply, you need to say what is.

PS. You can also implement the above logic by just comparing the start and end dates (day number). If they're different, it must have rolled over a month so set to 0.

Comment: This is an excellent answer @RobG Thank you for the detailed explanation. I never considered all the possibilities. I think the logic I will go with is to set the date to the end of the month 6 months before. Would you be able to edit my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Just change your `sixMonthBeforeNow` with the below code, that should work.

```
var sixMonthBeforeNow = new Date(now).setMonth(now.getMonth() - 6);
```

Comment: That doesn't always work, e.g. 31 August 2018 minus 6 months is 31 February, which converts to 3 March. In a leap year, it's 2 March. Similarly, 31 Jan minus 6 months is 31 Jul, but 31 December minus 6 months will be 1 July, and so on.